# Deploy an Actions on Google services in .net

Tags: c#, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm wondering if someone already tried to implement the actions sdk in c#.
I want to implement a gooogle action service but currently I'm a bit lost how the deployment procedure should be here.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement support for the Conversation API used in actions: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation

You have provide an HTTPS endpoint which will accept JSON payloads and then respond with the expected JSON responses.

The deployment process will be the same as for any action. That is not dependent on how you implement your HTTP endpoint.